# Valgrind Error Involving Uninitialised String: False Flag?

Tags: valgrind, c89

When running valgrind to check for errors in a program written in C89/90, it comes up with a `Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation` error for a `strToUpper()` function I wrote, despite the string being initialised.

I'm using this function to compare strings ignoring case. Unfortunately, C89 doesn't seem to include the `strcasecmp()` function in `<string.h>`, so I've written my own, which calls the `strToUpper()` and `strcmp()` functions.

### CODE

```c
char* strToUpper(char* inStr)
{
    int i;
    char *upperStr;
    size_t strLen = strlen(inStr);
    upperStr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strLen + 1));

    /* Does this for loop not initialise upperStr? */
    for (i = 0; i < strLen; i++)
        upperStr[i] = toupper(inStr[i]);

    return upperStr;
}
```

### VALGRIND ERROR

```
==27== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==27==    at 0x4C31FAA: strcmp (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27==    by 0x406649: strcasecmp (stringPlus.c:178)
==27==    ...
==27==    by 0x400FEB: main (main.c:58)
==27==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==27==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27==    by 0x4062E4: strToUpper (stringPlus.c:58)
==27==    by 0x406622: strcasecmp (stringPlus.c:175)
==27==    ...
==27==    by 0x400FEB: main (main.c:58)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not terminating your copied string.

Add something like

```
upperStr[i] = '\0';
```

after your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `malloc(blah)` I always use `calloc(1,blah)`. The latter sets all allocated memory to zero.